# N random choices according to probability

Tags: c, random

This code is used to get random numbers with a certain probability: 
8 is returned if `r` is between 0 and 0.8; 2 is returned if `r` is between 0.8 and 1.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    double r = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
    double sum = 8 + 2;
    if (r < 8 / sum) {
        printf("80% \n");
    } else {
        printf("20% \n");
    }  
}
```

but if I have more than two numbers, say n, how can I handle it? Can I handle it with multiple if-else statements? Or what else?

Comment: Just interested: why you asign 2 + 8? Why not just 10?

Comment: @Zaibis To make the logic clearer, maybe, shorter isn't always better

Comment: um, well it depends. If you could have many such values, looping over an array may be best, or if the values are determined by some formula, just a loop with the values. Or if it's a few fixed values, you could use a series of if/else. I don't really see the point of this question; what are you hoping to find out?

Comment: Can you give an example of input (e.g: [8,2]) and output (e.g: [80%, 20%]) that you wish to have for your N problem please?
You don't even need the if/else in the example you gave...

Comment: @Dave I want to distribute rand scope to multiple choices according to its weigh, for example if we have the choices :5,3,2,1 then I want 50% to 5, 30% to 3, 20% to 2, 10% to 1

Comment: you can accomplish that with a simple loop. I'd put it in a function which takes an array parameter (of the values) to keep it reusable. It sounds like you're quite new to this, so I'd recommend looking up arrays, looping and pointers.

Comment: Many programming languages have these things called "arrays" and "loops".

Comment: @pjs below has a better answer; since it also references the simpler solutions in mine, it would be better for other users if you switched the accepted answer to his.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simple**

1. Create an array of probabilities (sum to 1.0), in `O(n)` time
2. Generate a random number between 0.0 and 1.0
3. Iterate through the array, in `O(n)` time:

   - if the random number < the probability of the element, stop
   - otherwise decrement the random number by the probability and move to next element
4. The answer is the number corresponding to the element you stopped at

**Complex**

1. Create an array of *cumulative* probabilities and store them in an array, in `O(n)` time (this array should have increasing values)
2. Generate a random number between 0.0 and 1.0
3. Do a binary search to find the smallest element that is `>=` the random number, in `O(log(n))` time.
4. The answer is the number corresponding to the element you stopped at

I have not included the necessary corner cases to address. I am sure you can do it yourself.

Comment: see answer by @pjs for a more sophisticated solution that generates in `O(1)` and sets up in `O(n)`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to randomstring's proposals, you could consider building an [Alias Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250568/randomly-choosing-from-a-list-with-weighted-probabilities/17253335#17253335) -- O(n log n) to construct the table, O(1) per value to generate.

Comment: +1 better answer! i learned something new today :) hope he switches the accepted answer.